# Elasticsearch: Ngram tokenizer perfomance

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I try to search documents in elasticsearch with simple query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": { "name": "Test name" }
    }
}
```

and i have about 70 million documents in the index. I used whitespace tokenizer before, and it's works ok. But now i'm start using ngram, and even this queue runs for at least 6-7 seconds. I create index like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "custom_tokenizer": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "symbol",
                        "punctuation"
                    ],
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "max_gram": "3"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any ways to optimize the search? Or is ngram really that slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `ngram` is known to cause performance issues, as it creates many tokens, increase the Elasticsearch index size and `search terms` to match, one way to improve the performance is to use only in the queries where you really need it, for example in in-fix queries, if you share your search use-case, community might offer some other better alternatives.

Comment: Okay thank you. I was just wondering if ngram is really slower than whitespace. About query - there is an example at the beginning of my question, nothing complicated)

Comment: @kosoban, yes ngram will always be slower than the whitespace as it produces more tokens, and to generate them it has to do more processing and takes more space in the search index due to more tokens. if you can share your search case than I would be able to help you come with better index mapping and queries.